# How to merge / blur together a large amount of pictures on different layers

Tags: gimp, layers, blur

B"H

I have hundreds of pictures that I simply drag and drop from my filesystem to gimp, when it adds them each as a separate layer. I then manually drag each one to a place I want it on a page, then what I want to do is just to take the blur tool and blur everything such that everything is one big blob / tapestry together, such that one doesn't notice the hard edges.

What I can't figure out how to do is: how.

I'm aware one can blur each individual layer when clicking on it, but I want the blur t o apply to all pictures.

Comment: Photoshop = Group all layers, Convert to Smart Object, apply G-Blur Smart Filter.

Comment: @Scott - doesn't work in GIMP though. No smart objects, at least not yet, although I believe they are working on that.

Comment: I figured.. that's why it's a comment, not an answer `:)` Just in case Google hits this for a PS user.

Answer (score 1):

You can't edit several layers all in one go in GIMP. It's not possible. It might be possible to script something like this or to find a script that could apply a Gaussian blur to all layers.

One possible workaround is to merge visible layers before blurring, however this will remove all the layers. This is not ideal if you want to re-edit it in future.

Another possibility is to create a new layer from visible and blur that. Obviously this is still a destructive edit, but if you make sure it's the last thing you do in your editing process, then it may be an acceptable workaround. At least creating a new layer from visible will not remove your original layers.

Answer (score 1):

No Photoshop, must use freeware? If yes, then get Krita.

In Krita

- group your layers
- blur one of the layers, define the blur to be an ajdustment mask. It's like Photoshop's adjustment layer, but affects only to a single layer. NOTE: Adobe hasn't bothered to give to us blurs nor other widely used filters as adjustment layers.
- move the blur mask to the group-line in the layers panel.

No idea, how well this works in practice if you have 100 or 200 high pixel dimension layers. It seems to be a bit slow even with 3 layers of normal screen size.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Python console (`Filters > Python-fu > Console`):

The '>>>' is the command prompt, you don't need to enter that

1. get the image (this simplistic way works only if the image is the only one open in Gimp, or at least the last one you opened)

```
>>>image=gimp.image_list()[0]
```

2. resize all layers to the image size, and then blur them

```
for layer in image.layers: layer.resize_to_image_size() ; pdb.plug_in_gauss(image, layer, 30, 30, 0)
```

(replace the `30` by the size of the blur in pixels in X and Y respectively).

Warning: as written, if you want to undo you have to Ctrl-Z twice as many time as you have layers... This can be improved, but we are getting very close to writing a full script.